# The precision of the decimal number of the Cplex

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, cplex, c++

I have faced a little weird problem when I use Cplex to solve my test problem. Basically, some of my data are float numbers up to three decimal numbers (For instance, 0.627). But, when I print out the model using the `exportModel` command, I noticed that Cplex converts all the float numbers to numbers with much more degree of precision (For example, 0.627 to 0.626999974250793). As a result of this, Cplex gives me the wrong optimal solution. I'd be grateful if you could let me know what is the cause of this error and how I can prevent this convergence?

I should note that I use Concert technology C++.

Comment: 0.627 cannot be stored exactly in IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic. The decimal representation of the value that can actually be stored is 0.62699997425079345703125 . So numerically, everything is ok.

Comment: In what way is the optimal solution wrong (and by how much)?

Comment: Basically, the optimal objective value for the test instance I am dealing with, reported as 222 (It is a maximization problem). But, when I call Cplex, it reports 224 as the optimal objective value. When I use the original data that I have (with three decimal floating point) and verify the value of the decision variables given by Cplex, it gives the objective value of 126 !!! I also multiply all the float numbers by 1000. This time Cplex gives 223 as the optimal value

Comment: I just multiply all the float numbers by a very big number (100000000000), surprisingly Cplex reports the right optimal value (222)

Comment: I am still a bit confused. Is there any way to systematically avoid these sort of errors?

Answer (score 2):

instead of exporting into a .lp you could export into a .sav filre and then you won't face those rounding issues.

> SAV is a binary file format specific to CPLEX. This format is
> efficient for fast reading and writing of models and associated basis
> information. For example, it can effectively reduce read and write
> time for problems that are solved repetitively.
>
> Tip: CPLEX includes the basis in a SAV file only if the problem
> currently in memory has been optimized and a basis exists.
>
> This format also offers the **advantage of being numerically accurate**
> (to the same degree as your platform) in contrast to text file formats
> that may lose numerical accuracy. In other words, it provides a
> greater degree of precision in data. However, since a SAV file is
> binary, you cannot read nor edit it with your favorite text editor.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, would you mean that if I read the data from a .sav file, Cplex won't do conversions issues and I will work with exactly the same data I provided to it?

Comment: Yes that's it. Right

Comment: Great, many thanks !